# How to word it when you are asking for corrections

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's say I'm asking a coworker to review a proposal. I say:

> Could you find and fix mistakes, if any?

Should I put the article “the” before the word “mistakes” in that sentence?

> Could you find and fix **the** mistakes, if any?

Also, does “if any” sound natural? I mean to say “if there is” (if mistakes exist).

> Could you find and fix mistakes, if there is?
>   Could you find and fix mistakes, if they exist?

Comment: Could you please review this for any mistakes and correct them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in the sentences mentioned above.

> Could you find and fix mistakes, **if any?**

Usually, no comma is put in front of `if` but there appear to be some cases when this rule is overwritten.

On the other hand, `if any` is quite an elliptical phrase, there need to be put, for example, a subject into it.

> Find the mistakes **if there's any.** (NB: this is an imperative sentence)

Concerning **the**, I don't think it should be used because it is a definite article but the mistakes are unknown to the reader (co-worker) if they haven't read the text yet. Using **any** is a good quantifier to stand before **mistakes.** But if you stick to your plan (of using **the**), here's the following sentence I advise you to use:

> Could you please find the mistakes and fix **them** (if there's any)?

**Mistakes** is in plural, so the word that refers to it has to be **them.**